# How to use Boost.Filesystem standalone?

Tags: c++, boost

I haven't used Boost before and I want to change that now. But I only need one of its libraries which is Boost.Filesystem. I successfully built the libraries and linked the one from the `boost/libs/filesystem` folder to my Visual Studio project.

Then I copied `boost/filesystem.cpp` and the folder `boost/filesystem` with its content to the include directory of my project. But that wasn't enough since the compiler complained about many boost related files that were missing.

Here are some examples, but there are much more.

```
boost/utility/enable_if.hpp
boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp
boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp
boost/type_traits/decay.hpp
boost/system/system_error.hpp
...
```

How can I use Boost.Filesystem as a standalone library? I don't want to use the the whole collection since I want to store libraries in the project directory and therefore it would bloat up my project size unnecessarily.

Comment: If you're using VS2012 include the (as yet non-standard) `<filesystem>` header; it is based on Boost.FileSystem V3. Otherwise, AFAIK, there isn't a standalone version available. Also, IMO, your Boost installation should be managed separately from any of your projects, because you'll probably want to use Boost with more than one of your personal projects.

Comment: I know that it is recommended to install Boost separately but I have been doing well including all libraries into my project. It makes it much easier to checkout the project on another machine and continue working. I haven't heard of `<filesystem>` before, but it sounds great. Does it provide a way to get the last modified date of a file?

Comment: The implementation is based on a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3505.html) for C++14, and it borrows heavily from Boost.FileSystem. But since it isn't standardized, your code may break with future releases. As for specific features, I've never used it myself, so I don't know the answer to that question. But if the Boost version supports it, chances are the other one does too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `<filesystem>` works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: In order to easily develop on different systems you might want to take look at configuration and build systems like http://www.cmake.org/. Imho it is not a very good idea to take out one folder and file for your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you're using a library, you don't copy it into your project. Instead, you tell the compiler where it can go find it. In Linux this is extremely simple since there is a common place to put headers, a common place to put library files, etc. In Windows, you usually do this by adding locations to the include and library paths yourself, e.g.

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

Comment: So, Linux is better because a standard installation creates more directories? Nothing stopping you from creating those directories yourself on Windows. I'm perfectly happy with an OS not cluttering up my drive with directories for things I might need, or imposing its system of organization on me.

Comment: @CodyGray This discussion is off topic here. He just said that it is easier on Linux which is right since there are package managers allowing you to type a short command for downloading packages and installing them into a default directory.